# using js arrow function as a parameter

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm using an arrow function to pass a parameter to some other function. It looks sort of like this:

```
someFunction(parameter1, () => {
  return model.associatedGroups.filter(group => {
    return group.isAssociated === true;
   })
}, parameter3)
```

but when I'm debugging it, I'm receiving a function on the method i'm calling instead of a filtered array. How should I write it in order to get back a filtered array?

Comment: An arrow function is a function. You don't get the filtered array until `someFunction` calls the callback.

Comment: Why are you using an arrow function if you don't want it to be a function?

Comment: but I guess there could be some cases were you could use an arrow function to return value, and it will actually make sense, no? in these cases you would IIFE your function in order to get the value?

Comment: The only case would be if you're using `this` in the function, and you're using an arrow function to pass along the current value of `this`.

Answer (score 1):

You are just passing reference to a function.

Call the function in place to pass its result as the argument:

```
someFunction(
  parameter1, 
  (() => model.associatedGroups.filter(group => group.isAssociated === true))(), 
  parameter3
)
```

Or just pass the result of the filter:

```
someFunction(
  parameter1, 
  model.associatedGroups.filter(group => group.isAssociated === true), 
  parameter3
)
```

Or pass the function as you are already and call it within `someFunction` to get its result.

Comment: There's no point in using an IIFE in an argument like that. Just call `model.associatedGroups.filter()` in the argument.

Comment: @Barmar u'r absolutely right... How did I not see it??

Answer (score 0):

It's because you pass a function, not an array. If you want the result of this function you have to call it.

Moreover with arrow function you don't need to put `return if you have only one line.

Try with this:

```
someFunction(parameter1, (() => model.associatedGroups.filter(group => group.isAssociated === true))(), parameter3)
```

Edit : this is enought :)

```
someFunction(parameter1, model.associatedGroups.filter(group => group.isAssociated === true), parameter3)
```